# Converting from standard cookie format to LibCurl cookie jar format

Tags: cookies, converters, libcurl, netscape

Is there any convenient tool/code that converts the **standard cookie string format**, e.g., `NAME1: VALUE1; NAME2: VALUE2` to the **libCURL cookie jar format**, e.g., `.netscape.com     TRUE   /  FALSE  946684799   NETSCAPE_ID  100103`

LibCurl seems to have such functionality and how to access it, like using shell command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chrome extension, [edit this cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) has such functionality.

Cookies can be exported into the Netscape cookie jar format. Before that, you need to set the default output format to netscape cookie format.

Comment: This is awesome. Save my time. Thanks